# relative pathname and simple filename happen at the same time using `find` comman

Tags: linux, bash, shell

this question related to [missing-semester](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/shell-tools/) for its practice 5
and I try to use the command below

```
merose@DESKTOP-PG6TB9F:~/missing$ find . -atime -1 -exec ls -lt {} \;
total 1692
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 290196 Jul  5 20:19  output2.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 290196 Jul  4 22:29  output.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 836547 Jul  4 22:15  1.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 276563 Jul  4 22:15 '2 3.html'
-rwxr-xr-- 1 merose merose    153 Jul  4 21:55  caller.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose    227 Jul  4 21:48  out.txt
-rwxr-xr-- 1 merose merose    205 Jul  4 18:07  wrgchk.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose     18 Jul  4 17:19  polo.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose     26 Jul  4 17:13  marco.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose     37 Jul  2 22:19  last-modified.txt
-rwxr-xr-- 1 merose merose     51 Jul  2 22:09  semester
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose      6 Jul  2 21:19  hello.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 290196 Jul  5 20:19 ./output2.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 290196 Jul  4 22:29 ./output.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 276563 Jul  4 22:15 './2 3.html'
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 836547 Jul  4 22:15 ./1.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 merose merose 227 Jul  4 21:48 ./out.txt
-rwxr-xr-- 1 merose merose 153 Jul  4 21:55 ./caller.sh
```

as you can see,`hello.txt` and `./hello.txt` should be the same file but they occur in the result at the same time.Why would this happen?
And how could I avoid this situation

Comment: Please move your question to superuser.com or explain how this is related to programming

Comment: `find . -atime -1` outputs a `.` which runs `ls -lt .` which prints all files in current directory.

Comment: @KamilCuk Does it mean accutally it combines the result of `find` and `ls`?

Comment: I see only `hello.txt` in the output.

Comment: What do you see when you drop the whole `-exec` part from the `find` command?

Comment: @user1934428 sry I write it wrong, should be like `output.tar.gz` and `./output.tar.gz`

Comment: Right. Well, then KamilCuk explained well what happens here....